# What's wrong with my designs?

Tags: layout, composition, canvas

I designed almost 90% of the products on [this website](https://canvasheaven.com/).

We are not getting sales. Aside from marketing and sales strategy.

What do you think is wrong with my designs?

Comment: Hi Tarek, Welcome to graphicdesign.stackexchange. We hope your stay here is enjoyable and fulfilling.

Comment: Your question is slightly off-topic. I think your site products looks great. As far as no sales are concerned, I heard a colleague in advertising once tell a client, "When you don't promote, a terrible thing happens." … "Nothing."

Answer (score 2):

An opinion:

Designs are fine, but the products have premium prices. Of course $100,- gives also premium quality printing, but the price is still about ten times too high for a person who would order something printed from a web site.

I believe people who want to spend  $100,- to one piece of art want to see the piece in front of their eyes before buying and many of them expect a touch of handcrafting and uniqueness. Seeing only a web ad it's much easier to spend few bucks to a printed poster than $100,- to something which is presented as a printed alternative for a painting.

**Still something:** Your products are sold as products, they have been created by nobody. You should generate (if you haven't one) a good sounding and looking name of the artist which should be well visible. Do not try to sell printings but creations of an artist. If the artist has some history and personal saying, too, the better.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I really appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an area I've investigated myself...

I'm surprised you can get a museum-grade canvas & frame made for so little... Hannemuhle Monet or similar @30x40 would be about £350 here - but I think your break would be to get physical product into a couple of boutiques. As already said, people want to see & feel that kind of product before they buy it.

Alternatively, drop to cheap canvas & suck it up.
I get that size in  cheap generic canvas for £25, printed, framed & shipped, worldwide.

I think the ubiquity of 'print any old blurry jpg to your own canvas' sites these days makes standing out from the crowd an almost impossible task.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I really appreciate your response :)